# UIBarButtonItem have different space between

Tags: ios, xcode, ios7, uibarbuttonitem

I have six `UIBarButtonItem` on `self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems`. Every button has a png image that is 25x25 pixels. But as you can see in the image below the space between every button are different.

[image]

Why ? I would like that this space remains constantly for every space.

Comment: Try adding a flexible space between them to even the space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem are the png's inside the `UIBarButtonItem`. Probably they has blank pixels on the left/right that cause the issue.

Just using a flexible space between each button.